# Building OpenCV 2.3.1 with Python 2.7 support in Ubuntu 11.10 64bit

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv

I have seen a lot of posts on this topic, however I have not found regarding this warning:

```
CMake Warning:
   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

   BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT
```

when I compile with cmake. When building OpenCV with this warning, it turns out that it doesn't include python support (surprise).

I use this command to compile the build-files

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I have installed python-dev.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you're using an old install guide. Use `BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT` instead.

So, execute CMake like this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Also, if you use the CMake GUI, it is easier to see all of the options you can set for OpenCV (there are so many it's quite tedious to type them all on the command-line). To get it for Ubuntu, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake-qt-gui
```

Comment: oh, man. I thought I had some library missing. I installed numpy multiple times. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple instructions to install opencv with python bindings in Linux - Ubuntu/Fedora**

1. Install gcc, g++/gcc-c++, cmake  (apt-get or yum, in case of yum
   use gcc-c++).
   **#apt-get install gcc, g++, cmake**
2. Downlaod latest opencv from openCV's website
   (http://opencv.org/downloads.html).
3. Untar it  **#tar - xvf opencv-*****
4. Inside the untarred folder make a new folder called "**release**" (or
   any folder name) and run this command in it #**"cmake -D
   CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D
   BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .."** the ".." will pull
   files from the parents folder and will get the system ready for
   installation on your platform.
5. in the release (#cd release) folder run **#make**
6. After about 2-3 mins of make processing when its finished run
   **#make install**

That's it, now go to python and try ">>> **import cv2**" you should not get any error message.

Tested on python 2.7, should be virtually similar to python 3.x.